# How can I run cmd commands inside a PowerShell session?

Tags: powershell, cmd

I can't run cmd command inside PowerShell session although I type "cmd /c" before the command itself as shown below I got the following error:

```
PS C:\Program Files (x86)\FireEye\xagt> cmd /c xagt.exe -g "C:\tmp\xagt_%computername%_%date:~-4,4%%date:~-10,2%%date:~-7,2%_%time:~0,2%%time:~3,2%%time:~6,2%.txt"

cmd : Fail to parse the argument: 95319.txt
At line:1 char:1
+ cmd /c xagt.exe -g "C:\tmp\xagt_%computername%_%date:~-4,4%%date:~-10 ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (Fail to parse the argument: 95319.txt:String) [], RemoteException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NativeCommandError
```

If I run the following command in cmd console session as shown below, I got a successful result that a file named "xagt_servername_20232405_151403.txt" has been generated in c:\tmp, this command generates a log file that has the name "xagt_servername_date_serialnumber"

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\FireEye\xagt\xagt.exe" -g "C:\tmp\xagt_%computername%_%date:~-4,4%%date:~-10,2%%date:~-7,2%_%time:~0,2%%time:~3,2%%time:~6,2%.txt"

success
```

The strange thing is, if I run the following script using PowerShell after I have run the command in cmd console session, the cmd inside the PowerShell run successfully and generate another log file in c:\tmp

The PowerShell script as follows:

```
Write-Host "----------------------------------------"
            Write-Host ""##############Microsoft Fireeye   Info###############""
            Write-Host "----------------------------------------`r`n"

Get-ChildItem -Path 'HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall'  | Get-ItemProperty |   where {$_.DisplayName -like 'FireEye Endpoint Agent'} | Select DisplayName, Publisher, InstallDate,DisplayVersion

cd "C:\Program Files (x86)\FireEye\xagt\"
cmd /c xagt.exe -g "C:\tmp\xagt_%computername%_%date:~-4,4%%date:~-10,2%%date:~-7,2%_%time:~0,2%%time:~3,2%%time:~6,2%.txt"
```

I got no errors and another log file is created in c:\tmp. I don't know why it doesn't work from the first attempt.

I try to run cmd commands usig PowerShell using the following:

```
Start-Process -FilePath "xagt.exe" -WorkingDirectory "C:\Program Files (x86)\FireEye\xagt\" -ArgumentList "-g","`C:\tmp\xagt_%computername%_%date:~-4,4%%date:~-10,2%%date:~-7,2%_%time:~0,2%%time:~3,2%%time:~6,2%.txt`""
```

But it didn't generate the log file as expected.

I also tried:

```
PS C:\Program Files (x86)\FireEye\xagt> .\xagt.exe -g "C:\tmp\xagt_%computername%_%date:~-4,4%%date:~-10,2%%date:~-7,2%_%time:~0,2%%time:~3,2%%time:~6,2%.txt"

.\xagt.exe : Error: -4058
At line:1 char:1
+ .\xagt.exe -g "C:\tmp\xagt_%computername%_%date:~-4,4%%date:~-10,2%%d ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (Error: -4058:String) [], RemoteException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NativeCommandError
```

Another try:

```
PS C:\Program Files (x86)\FireEye\xagt> cmd /c xagt.exe -g "C:\tmp\xagt_%computername%_%date:~-4,4%%date:~-10,2%%date:~-7,2%_%time:~0,2%%time:~3,2%%time:~6,2%.txt"

cmd : Fail to parse the argument: 95319.txt
At line:1 char:1
+ cmd /c xagt.exe -g "C:\tmp\xagt_%computername%_%date:~-4,4%%date:~-10 ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (Fail to parse the argument: 95319.txt:String) [], RemoteException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NativeCommandError
```

Comment: Looks like `%time%` has leading _space_ if used _ante meridiem_ (your constant `95319` corresponds to 9 hours, 53 minutes and 19 seconds…

Comment: Use `Get-Date -Format` instead of parsing %DATE% and %TIME%.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's great information in the comments, and [JosefZ](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3439404/josefz) has provided the crucial pointer: your command failed, because cmd.exe's dynamic `%TIME%` variable has a *leading space* for all single-digit (morning) hours; e.g.  `9:29:16.15`; this space caused an *extra argument* to be passed.

Let me add a PowerShell-only solution that bypasses your problem and is both simpler and more efficient, given that you don't need to call via `cmd.exe`:

```bash
xagt.exe -g "C:\tmp\xagt_${env:COMPUTERNAME}_$(Get-Date -Format 'yyyyMMdd_HHmmss').txt"
```

The above uses:

- an [expandable (double-quoted) PowerShell string (`"..."`)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Quoting_Rules#double-quoted-strings), in which variable references - such as environment-variable reference `$env:COMPUTERNAME` - can be embedded, as well as, via `$(...)`, commands and expressions, such as the `Get-Date` call.
- a call to the [`Get-Date`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/Microsoft.PowerShell.Utility/Get-Date) cmdlet with its `-Format` parameter, which allows you to format a date and time as desired, such as via [custom date and time format strings](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-date-and-time-format-strings).

  - Note that the use of `HH` for the hour of the day causes single-digit hours to be left-padded with a `0`, e.g. `09`, and PM hours to be expressed in 24-hour format, e.g. `15` for 3 PM.

Comment: really appreciate your kind support

Comment: My pleasure, @user3737708; glad to hear the answer helped.